# Add custom formula to webdatarocks

Tags: webdatarocks

Is it possible with webdatarocks to calculate % of difference per row for each period?
I want to add 3rd column and get % od difference for "Sum of foodDonorDelta" so for 30/09/2020 it will be null, for 31/10/2020 it will be 4000%, for 30/11/2020 it will be -78% and for 31/12/2020 it will be 1000%.
I Know I can set "% Difference" in fields options

[image]

but then I have to move "Values" to "Rows" while I need them in "Columns"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The %difference aggregation function of WebDataRocks has the following logic:

If the Values are in Rows, the %difference will be calculated based on the Sum row. In case Values are in Columns, the %difference will be calculated based on the Sum column.

So it is possible to calculate the %difference between Sum values per row, but only when the Values are in Rows.